# New to Java. Getting strange error in calculator program when pressing any button

Tags: java, user-interface, calculator, eventqueue

I've only been working with Java for about a month now so I don't exactly have a complete grasp on it yet. I have been assigned to make a calculator program with a GUI for class. I got everything working besides the fact that the user can enter in multiple decimal points. So I tried to fix that problem (which I did not) and now the program will run without any errors but whenever I click a button, such as 1, 2, 3, or an operator such as +, -, etc. I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at inlab05.InLab05$event.actionPerformed(InLab05.java:190)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

And here is the part of the code where I believe the error lies:

```
public class event implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
        String text = a.getActionCommand();


        if (text.equals("1")) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "1");
        } else if (text.equals("2")) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "2");
        } else if (text.equals("3")) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "3");
        } else if (text.equals("4")) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "4");
        } else if (text.equals("5")) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "5");
        } else if (text.equals("6")) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "6");
        } else if (text.equals("7")) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "7");
        } else if (text.equals("8")) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "8");
        } else if (text.equals("9")) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "9");
        } else if (text.equals("0")) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + "0");
        } else if (text.equals(".")) {
            result.setText(result.getText() + ".");
        }


        String str = result.getText();
        textBox = Double.parseDouble(str);

        if (a.getSource()
                == textAdd) {
            op = 1;
            firstInput = textBox;
            result.setText("");
        }

        if (a.getSource()
                == textSubtract) {
            op = 2;
            firstInput = textBox;
            result.setText("");
        }

        if (a.getSource()
                == textMultiply) {
            op = 3;
            firstInput = textBox;
            result.setText("");
        }

        if (a.getSource()
                == textDivide) {
            op = 4;
            firstInput = textBox;
            result.setText("");
        }

        if (a.getSource()
                == textPercent) {
            op = 5;
            firstInput = textBox;
            result.setText("");
        }

        if (a.getSource()
                == textSqrt) {
            op = 6;
            firstInput = textBox;
            answer = Math.sqrt(textBox);
            str = Double.toString(answer);
            result.setText(str);
        }

        if (a.getSource()
                == textSign) {
            double neg;
            op = 7;
            neg = 0 - textBox;
            str = Double.toString(neg);
            result.setText(str);
        }

        if (a.getSource()
                == textEqual) {
            if (op == 1) {
                answer = firstInput + textBox;
                str = Double.toString(answer);
                result.setText(str);
            } else if (op == 2) {
                answer = firstInput - textBox;
                str = Double.toString(answer);
                result.setText(str);
            } else if (op == 3) {
                answer = firstInput * textBox;
                str = Double.toString(answer);
                result.setText(str);
            } else if (op == 4) {
                answer = firstInput / textBox;
                str = Double.toString(answer);
                result.setText(str);
            } else if (op == 5) {
                answer = firstInput % textBox;
                str = Double.toString(answer);
                result.setText(str);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the code is the GUI and what not.

Does anyone know what this could be? I don't remember changing anything that I know of when I was trying to fix my decimal point issue and I changed the code back to how it previously was when it last worked

The error says it occurs at line 190 which is `result.setText(result.getText() + "1");`

Of course if I click a different button the line number will change, that is just an example if the user pressed the number 1 button

Sorry for such a long post hopefully you guys can help :)

Comment: What's strange about the error?

Comment: `"And here is the part of the code where I believe the error lies: ..."` -- You know **exactly** where the error lies as the JVM tells you that it is occurring here: `InLab05.java:190` at line 190 of InLab05.java. Please show the code for this class and indicate which line is this one. You are trying to de-reference / call a method on a variable with a null reference on that line.

Comment: `if (text.length() == 1 && "1234567890.".contains(text)) result.setText(result.getText() + text)` replaces all your fancy `if else` construct

Comment: Thanks @zapl I did that and I still get the same error. It is nice to know the shorter route of doing that though. Also I edited the post to show what line the error occurs on

Answer (score 0):

If are using any kind of IDE (Eclipse, NetBeans, ...) you can even click on the *InLab05.java:190* part of the

```
at inlab05.InLab05$event.actionPerformed(InLab05.java:190)
```

and will take you straight where the NullPointerException happens.

Answer (score 0):

> The error says it occurs at line 190 which is result.setText(result.getText() + "1");

So the result variable ***at this location in your program*** is null. You will need to look back into your code to see why it has not been initialized in this scope/context.

---

**Edit 1**
Search throughout your code for the result variable. The variable that is being used on the offending line has not been initialized. Be watchful for variable shadowing though where a field of the class is re-declared in a constructor or method.

---

**Edit 2**
You state:

> Where I initialize the result variable (JTextField result = new JTextField();) result is underlined in yellow and says "Local variable hides a field" and the only option it gives me is to rename the variable. Could that have something to do with it?

Yes. You're doing exactly what I worried you might be doing. By re-declaring the result variable at that location, you end up initializing a local variable whose scope is only within the method or constructor that it was declared in, and the field in the class remains null. Change that line from:

```
JTextField result = new JTextField(); // re-declaring variable here
```

to:

```
result = new JTextField(); // not re-declaring variable here
```

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure where that would be since I don't remember changing anything. I'll take a closer look at it right now

Comment: @MarkShimala: search throughout your code for the `result` variable. The variable that is being used on the offending line has not been initialized. Be watchful for variable shadowing though where a field of the class is re-declared in a constructor or method.

Comment: Where I initialize the result variable (JTextField result = new JTextField();) result is underlined in yellow and says "Local variable hides a field" and the only option it gives me is to rename the variable. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: @MarkShimala: you're welcome. Look up "Variable Shadowing" for more on this problem.